# "No Key Defined" error message, when creating a view for a view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I am creating a project following  'MVC Music Store' tutorial, when come to create a view for "ShoppingCartViewModel", it always shows the error that tells me that there is no **Key definied**.
The error message is: Entity type'ShoppingCartViewModel' has no key defined....

Here is the original code from the tutorial:

```
namespace MyMVStore.ViewModels
{
     public class ShoppingCartViewModel
    {

       public List<Cart> CartItems { get; set; }
       public decimal? CartTotal { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Here is what I updated:

```
//[NotMapping]
namespace MyMVStore.ViewModels
{
     public class ShoppingCartViewModel
    {
       [Key] //my code
       public int Id { get; set; } // my code
       public List<Cart> CartItems { get; set; }
       public decimal? CartTotal { get; set; }
   }
}
```

I put [Key] and Id to the model, seems not working. I also tried to add [Notmapping], it doesn't work either. The error massage still showing up when I tried to create the view for this model.

Comment: A view model does not need a `[Key]` attribute (that associated with data models/EF only). You seem to be associating this model with EF.

Comment: When I was creating the view, I was tried to bind the view with my model (I pick the model from "Model class" drowdown list, then I only have two choice on Data context class: my option is EF.  So you are right, it is associated with EF.

Comment: @HelenZH, Did you find the answer or a workaround for this question? I also have the same issue here

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is remove the `DataContext` class from the dropdown. It's an editable dropdown, so you can just highlight it and delete it.
It works fine after you do that.

Comment: When I removed it the "Add" button disabled and won't let me create the views. I use EF6 but I'm not binding the data model directly but a view model with some of the properties that I only want to display and edit in views. These fields has data annotations too. I'm working on VS 2015

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have declared DbSet in your context class, which is associated with EF. Remove the declaration to make it a non-table model.