# mvc entity type has no key defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC,

I use Visual Studio 2015, EF6

I created new web project and followed step by step with this tutorial (trying to learn):
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1

I am now in part 8, i created the ShoppingCartController, ShoppingCartViewModel, ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel.

Now, according to the instructions under the "Ajax Updates with jQuery" headline, i should create Shopping Cart Index page that is strongly typed to the ShoppingCartViewModel and uses the List View template.

But when i am trying to do that, i get an error
[image]

How can i solve this?

EDIT:

```
public class ShoppingCartViewModel
    {
        public List<Cart> CartItems { get; set; }
        public decimal CartTotal { get; set; }
    }
```

Exactly as shown in the tutorial...

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the contents of your ShoppingCartViewModel class?

Comment: To Update, add [Key] Attribute to the primary Key of ShoppingCart class of the model.

Comment: David - i just edited my post with the code you asked.

Comment: M.Hassan - the ShoppingCart class in the Model folder have only logic functions, not table with columns definitions, so there is nothing to give a [Key] for...

Comment: Why you're trying to learn very old framework (i.e MVC 3 ) ? and that article was published on `April 21, 2011`.Don't you like to learn new things ? Like Asp.net core MVC 1.0 ?

Comment: i work on MVC 5, but the idea of understanding how the MVC work is the same if you are on MVC 3 or MVC 5... if you have a good tutorial like the one i gave here, with full project, very specific details for each step, i will have a look there too, till then, i need help with my current problem. thanks

Comment: Had the same problem today - found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40940625/55640

Answer (score 0):

Yes,According to your comment above where I would like to recommend to follow below mentioned tutorial. Which is nicely matched with your current path too.That is `MVC 5`.Please see that.Good Luck!

[**Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

For your problem above where you can download the source code of the above tutorial and then you can find out the issue by your self.

Here is the link for that : [**Source code**](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Every Entity needs a Primary Key and there are several ways to set one up.

EF will automatically infer a key if a property in the class is named ID like so:

```
public int ID {get;set;}
```

Or you can use an attribute to specify a specific property as the key:

```
[Key]
public int SomeKey {get;set;}
```

Naming a class XXViewModel implies it's not a persisted class (not saved in the database). So a **Model** is a class you are saving in the database, and a **ViewModel** is a class you use to pass data to your view.

So your Model would be this:

```
public class ShoppingCartModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID {get;set;}

    public List<Cart> CartItems { get; set; }
    public decimal CartTotal { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Wurd, but according to your answer, if my class is XXViewModel (which it is) than no need for Key because it is not in the database... so i am not sure how your answer help me, maybe i did not understand you correctly. my class is a ViewModel, so why i get an error that my class is missing Key?